# How do I clean and lubricate the mortise lock on my front door

Tags: doors, cleaning, lock

The latch bolt in the mortise lock on my front door hangs, presumably because of built up grime. At any rate it gets stuck before exiting the faceplate fully (see picture below), resulting in it not entering the strike plate.

I want to try to clean the lock and then lubricate it, but I am uncertain about the best way to go about it. Can someone here please give some advice on how to best fix my door?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wd40?

Comment: @Questor wd40 is not a long term solution for lubricating stuff like this.

Comment: @ratchetfreak It works wonders for cleaning...

Comment: So does compressed air, @Questor without leaving a mess behind...

Comment: WD40 turns into sticky goo after a few years. Unscrupulous locksmiths can guarantee repeat business by using WD40 liberally on locks that they service.

Comment: I was thinking about trying this, as it's a solvent I have lying around: https://www.arrowchem.com/products/supersolve-as/ However, I was a bit uncertain as I've not used it to clean stuff like this before, and I won't be able to get into the lock to wipe away anything. I did have a look at some other questions on this site, and saw that they generally advised against WD40... Tbh, I kinda suspect the previous owner used something like that, and that is the origin of the problems I have today.

Comment: For locks you want a dry lubricant to avoid attracting dirt. If somebody already sprayed WD40 in there, then more of the stuff is might be okay for cleaning away the old stuff plus accumulated dirt. That feels like "doubling down on stupid," however. WD40 actually owns a "dry" lock lubricant brand. That stuff, graphite powder, etc. is what you want if the lock hasn't already been contaminated with oil and dirt.

Comment: Brake cleaner is my first instinct for removing old oil. Comes with a straw and everything.

Comment: if it's already had WD40, your lock is addicted, and graphite powder will make it worse until you detox by stripping the lock and degrease all the moving parts. While graphite is the elite way of doing it, WD40 is going to be way better than as-is. You put a rag under the opening and blast short bursts into the crevice until the bubbly juice spilling onto the rag runs clear. Then lock and unlock a million times (ok, like a dozen) and your good for a long while.

Answer (score 1):

To *clean* the lock: disassemble and remove the handles, loosen and remove the lock cylinder(s) and/or thumbturns (remove edge cover plate, loosen setscrews a few turns, unscrew these from the lock body or in Europe slide the cylinder assembly out), dismount the lock body (remove screws, slide out), open the lock body, remove dirt/dust, check whether springs are still strong enough, check for unreasonable amounts of wear, replace parts that are worn out (if you can), lubricate (see below), reassemble everything in reverse order of disassembly, check that it all works and nothing is loose enough to move in ways it shouldn't or too tight to move in ways it should.

Traditionally, the latch mechanism was lubricated with a light grease. This is not a place where precision matters much; you just need things to slide reasonably easily and not wear out too fast.

Graphite powder used to be the locksmith's go-to for lubricating precision moving parts such as the lock mechanism (the parts that recognize the key). It can still be used, but many (most?) locksmiths have moved to a silicon microsphere lubricant such as Tri-Flo. These go on wet but the carrier evaporates away leaving a dusting of, essentially, microscopic ball bearings. This has the same advantages as graphite but doesn't have the risk of being overapplied, and has some of the same cleaning properties WD40 claims.

(I am *not* in the no-WD40 camp. If treated as a cleaner, to be followed with the proper lubricant, my experience is that it's harmless at worst.)

Comment: Graphite powder is also very easy to obtain in small quantities. Take a pencil, a box cutter, and shave off some lead. See if that helps.

Comment: Trivia: commercial graphite powder is fine enough that it can be used to lift fingerprints.

Comment: Graphite powder is cheap at most hardware stores and locksmiths a few dollars for a tube that should be good for many applications if not overapplied.